# Word interop cross referencing an endnote

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop, netoffice

I am trying to refer to an existing end note in word from a table cell in the document thus (using netoffice):

```
row.Cells[2].Range.InsertCrossReference(WdReferenceType.wdRefTypeEndnote, WdReferenceKind.wdEndnoteNumberFormatted, 1);
```

However, this appears to put the reference at the beginning of the row, rather than at the end of the text at Cell[2]. In general, I haven't found much help on the web on how to programmatically add a cross-reference to footnotes and end notes.  How can I get the reference to display properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the target `Range` specified in your code snippet is the entire cell. You need to "collapse" the `Range` to be within the cell. (Think of the Range like a Selection. If you click at the edge of a cell, the entire cell is selected, including its structural elements. If you then press left-arrow, the selection is collapsed to a blinking I-beam.)

To go to the start of the cell:

```
Word.Range rngCell = row.Cells[2].Range;
rngCell.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseStart);
rngCell.InsertCrossReference(WdReferenceType.wdRefTypeEndnote, WdReferenceKind.wdEndnoteNumberFormatted, 1);
```

If the cell has content and you want it at the end of the content, then you use `wdCollapseEnd` instead. The tricky part about that is this puts the target point at the start of the next cell, so it has to be moved back one character:

```
Word.Range rngCell = row.Cells[2].Range;
rngCell.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);
rng.MoveEnd(Word.WdUnits.wdCharacter, -1);
rngCell.InsertCrossReference(WdReferenceType.wdRefTypeEndnote, WdReferenceKind.wdEndnoteNumberFormatted, 1);
```

Comment: Very good and informative answer and it solved my problem. But I still don't understand why my reference appeared before at the beginning of the row (which is beginning of Cell[1] rather than Cell[2]).

Comment: I don't *know*, but I would assume it's a default behavior in the Word code. Something along the lines of: If the target range in a table isn't usable (i.e. contains cell or row structures) go to the beginning of the row. But that's just my guess...